# Why Google maps API results are not accurate?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

We use premium plan for **google maps api** lookup and encountering accuracy issues while using it I for the following . But these are just examples, there could be many

52241 (should be Coralville, pulling Iowa City )

43065 (should be Powell, pulling Shawnee Hills)

11040 (should be New Hyde park, pulling Garden City ).

we use the following URL: 
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|postal_code:

Comment: How are you "pulling" the value from the API?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The postal codes that you mentioned in your question overlap several localities. Google shows in address component one locality, probably the most prominent on their opinion.

However, in the response you can see a list of localities that the postal code overlaps. Just look at the `postcode_localities` field in the response.

E.g., for postal code 52241

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A52241%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you will see

```
"place_id":"ChIJbaAjdYZD5IcRBfptU5KhMJk",
"postcode_localities":[
    "Coralville","Iowa City","Oakdale"
],
"types":[
    "postal_code"
]
```

For postal code 43065

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A43065%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

response will contain

```
"place_id":"ChIJW2TudRTsOIgR8v0-4d19bNA",
"postcode_localities":[
    "Powell","Shawnee Hills"
],
"types":[
    "postal_code"
]
```

And finally for postal code 11040

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=postal_code%3A11040%7Ccountry%3AUS&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

you will get

```
"place_id":"ChIJ28UCx5hiwokRf_9UXmJHg5I",
"postcode_localities":[
    "GARDEN CITY P","Garden City Park","Hillside Manor","Manhasset Hills","New Hyde Park","North Hills","North New Hyde Park"
],
"types":[
    "postal_code"
]
```

Note that localities you were looking for are present in the `postcode_localities` arrays.

I hope this helps!